# Back arrow won't trigger onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar, fragment, back

I want add confirmation dialog before my fragment close. I have added the onOptionsItemSelected function in my fragment. however when i click the back arrow button the function is not executed. Here's my code

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.show()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_input, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> "testing".debugTag("Debug")
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the action bar in onCreate.

```
setSupportActionBar( yourActionBar );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already write it in my MainActivity (parent activity of the fragment). I also tried your recommendation, but the result is same.